# Selecting visual block in the middle of a sentece accross multiple lines in Vim

Tags: vim

So, let's imagine I have this code:

```
print $this_one   = "1";
print $this_tu    = "2";
print $this_three = "3";
```

and I want to select the middle part using the visual block mode:

```
$this_one   
$this_tu    
$this_three
```

and perhaps append something etc. but that's not important now.

The problem I am facing is that I don't know how to select that.

If it were something like:

```
print $this_one;
print $this_tu;
print $this_three;
```

I would just press Ctrl + v then j j and $ and it would be done.

But what if it is in the middle and the words end up on a different columns?

Comment: I don't believe that is something that can be done.

Comment: It's frustrating, because this is like three clicks with mouse in Sublime while in Vim I need to use a macro if I want to do that and that is a lot of keypresses ;(

Comment: You probaly need some plugin. Maybe https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors

Comment: But I use vim mode in VS Code, Emacs, Kate and other software as well, not only in Vim inside a terminal ;(

Answer (score 1):

The blockwise selection with a jagged right edge indeed only works at the end of lines. **In the "middle", you're stuck with a rectangular block selection that then includes trailing whitespace.**

Unless you switch to a completely different approach (the comments already mention [vim-multiple-cursors](https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors), which lets you select multiple places and then you can interactively edit all of those in parallel), you have to live with that.

Depending on the command that is applied to the blockwise selection, the trailing whitespace (or even any other characters you inadvertently capture) doesn't necessarily harm.

To append a character (say, `$`) to all middle words in your example, I would use the [vis.vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1195)'s `:B` command to work on the selection only, moving to the end of the word with the `E` motion, then appending the character with `a$`:

```
:'<,'>B normal! Ea$
```

In this, the whitespace is kept, and everything to the right of the selection moves one character right.